# How to Save Images from ImageView in specific Folder from Whatsapp .Status Folder in Android 11

Tags: android, directory, create-directory, save-image

I like to save Images Which I take from .status Folder from Whatsapp So I would like to know How to access .Status Folder of Whatsapp and Save that Image in My own define Folder in Android 11 (Scope Storage)

Comment: Did you try to do it in the normal way? Just copying some files. Which problems did you encounter?

Comment: I don't Know where to start

Answer (score 0):

Use SAF framework to access WhatsApp .Status Directory

```
private fun askPermission() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    intent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    val startDir = "Android%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2.Statuses"
    var uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI")
    uri?.apply {

        uri = Uri.parse(startDir)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```